# Hyper-V Script Won't Recognize Remote Virtual Machines

Tags: powershell, scripting, hyper-v, hypervisor

I am creating a PowerShell script to be run as a scheduled task. It's purpose is to create a snapshot on each of our virtual machines every Monday. I've created a short script for each VM. After establishing a remote session to our local Hyper-V server, it should simply find our virtual machine and create a Snapshot. This is what it looks like when testing:

```
PS C:\Users\crhoden\Documents\Scripts\HyperV Snapshot Job> .\win7

Name                               State CPUUsage(%) MemoryAssigned(M) Uptime   Status             Version
----                               ----- ----------- ----------------- ------   ------             -------
Windows 10 Professional            Off   0           0                 00:00:00 Operating normally 7.0
Windows 7 Professional Pre-Alpha   Saved 0           0                 00:00:00 Operating normally 7.0
Windows 8.1 Professional Pre-Alpha Off   0           0                 00:00:00 Operating normally 7.0
Windows Server 2012 R2             Off   0           0                 00:00:00 Operating normally 7.0
Get-VMSnapshot : Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual machine with name "Windows 7 Pro".
At C:\Users\crhoden\Documents\Scripts\HyperV Snapshot Job\Win7.ps1:6 char:1
+ Get-VMSnapshot -VMName $vmname | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt (G ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-VMSnapshot], VirtualizationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ObjectNotFound,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.GetVMSnapshot

Checkpoint-VM : Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual machine with name "Windows 7 Pro".
At C:\Users\crhoden\Documents\Scripts\HyperV Snapshot Job\Win7.ps1:7 char:1
+ Checkpoint-VM -Name $vmname -SnapshotName "Weekly Snapshot $((Get-Dat ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Checkpoint-VM], VirtualizationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ObjectNotFound,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.CheckpointVM



[hypervserver]: PS C:\Users\crhoden\Documents> get-vm

Name            State   CPUUsage(%) MemoryAssigned(M) Uptime      Status
----            -----   ----------- ----------------- ------      ------
Windows 10 Pro  Running 1           1172              1.00:49:27  Operating normally
Windows 7 Pro   Running 0           1024              10:54:07    Operating normally
Windows 8 Pro   Running 0           1159              16.22:02:43 Operating normally
Windows 8.1 Pro Running 1           1716              16.21:43:03 Operating normally


[hypervserver]: PS C:\Users\crhoden\Documents>
```

As you can probably tell, when I manually run a "get-vm", the remote machines turn up just fine. But when ran as a script, it still searches my workstation instead. Here are the contents of the script:

```
Enter-pssession -computername hypervserver
start-sleep -s 10
cd C:\
$vmname = 'Windows 7 Pro'
get-vm
Get-VMSnapshot -VMName $vmname | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-15) } | Remove-VMSnapshot
Checkpoint-VM -Name $vmname -SnapshotName "Weekly Snapshot $((Get-Date).toshortdatestring())"
```

I added the start-sleep command as an attempted fix, thinking commands were firing before the connection was established. No such luck. The kicker is if I run through this script line by line, it works just fine. Any help is appreciated. EDIT: It also works perfect when pasting in the contents of the script in their entirety.

Comment: AFAIK Enter-PSSession is for interactive use, so you ***have*** to be interactive. OTOH [Get-VMSnapShot](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh848569.aspx) has a `-ComputerName` parameter to address the Hyper-V host(s) so why don't you use that?

Comment: Tried `-ComputerName` as you recommended. Now getting error saying the Hyper-V module PowerShell is using is not compatible. Will load a compatible module (if possible) and update.

Comment: Okay, so it turns out that there's two seperate Hyper-V modules Win10 (my OS) uses. 2.0, and 1.1 which is compatible with HyperVServer2012r2 (my Hyper-V OS).   To remotely manage older versions, you have to remove the new module and import the older one. After that, your suggestion worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Enter-PSSession` is for interactive sessions only, so working interactively or pasting into a session does work, but not in a script which is by nature not interactive.

You can either

- execute the script remotely or
- use the `-ComputerName` parameter of `Get-VMSnapShot`

As you discovered by yourself the used cmdlet has to match the Hyper-Vserver version.